# Late static bindings in Java

Tags: java, php

PHP has a feature called *late static bindings* where the `static` keyword is resolved at runtime and refers to the class currently executing the code. Consider the following PHP code:

```
class Collection
{
    protected $items;

    public function __construct(array $items = [])
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function map(Closure $closure)
    {
        return new static(array_map($closure, $this->items));
    }
}

class CatCollection extends Collection {}
```

If we were to create an instance of `Collection` we would be able to call its `map` method and that would return an instance of `Collection`. Similarly, we could create an instance of `CatCollection` and call its `map` method and that would yield a new instance of `CatCollection` (rather than `Collection`).

```
$collection = new Collection([1, 2, 3]);
$doubled = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return $item * 2;
}); // Returns an instance of Collection containing items 2, 4, 6.

$cats = new CatCollection(['Keyboard', 'Grumpy']);
$titled = $cats->map(function ($cat) {
    return 'Mr. ' . $cat;
}); // Returns an instance of CatCollection containing items 'Mr. Keyboard', 'Mr. Grumpy'.
```

- Is it possible to do something like this in Java? That is, to have a parent define functionality such that when it is executed in the context of a child class, it acts in the context of the child using the parent's implementation (Like in the PHP example above). I am fairly confident that this is not possible without using reflection or some kind of hack.
- Are there techniques or patterns that developers often use to achieve the same, or similar result?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do stuff like that using some generic tomfoolery...

(In the below; `E` is the type of *elements* of the `MyCollection` and `C` is the type of the *extension* of `MyCollection`.)

```
abstract class MyCollection<E, C extends MyCollection<E, C>> {

    private final List<E> elements;

    MyCollection(final List<E> elements) {
        this.elements = new ArrayList<>(elements);
    }

    C map(final UnaryOperator<E> mapper) {
        final List<E> mappedElements = new ArrayList<>(this.elements.size());
        for (final E element : this.elements) {
            mappedElements.add(mapper.apply(element));
        }

        return this.create(mappedElements);
    }

    abstract C create(final List<E> mappedElements);
}

class SubCollection<E> extends MyCollection<E, SubCollection<E>> {

    SubCollection(final List<E> elements) {
        super(elements);
    }

    @Override 
    SubCollection<E> create(final List<E> mappedElements) {
        return new SubCollection<>(mappedElements);
    }
}
```

I can't think of a time I've ever had to do this sort of thing though...